# Dynamic gallery grid

Tags: javascript, html

I have a folder which is updated every 5 minute or so with new image files.

I need to create a html page with  a gallery grid of the image thumbnails (along with the image title) from the above mentioned folder. How can I achieve that?

Comment: do you know `jquery` ?

Comment: you should illustrate your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used php foreach and glob  to achieve this.

```
       <?php

        $dir = "upload/";
        $loopthru= glob($dir."*.jpg");
        foreach($loopthru as $image) 
        {
        echo '<img src="'.$image.'" width="300" height="200">';
        }

        ?>
```